# Cannot Select Radio Buttons in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, radio-button

I am creating a group of radio buttons but it's very strange that I cannot select any of them. When I hover over the radio buttons, it just disappears like in pic2. When I move out the mouse, it will show up again. I do have ids, names, values for these buttons and this issue exists everywhere in my Angular app. Anyone had similar issue before?

[radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkw0A.png)

[radio buttons when hover over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXIss.png)

code here:

```
 <div>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="Radio1" />Radio 1<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="Radio2"/>Radio 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="Radio3"/>Radio 3<br /><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Update: This issue only exists in Chrome, it works perfectly in IE.

Update2: It turns out it's CSS that's causing this issue. Ultimately I found this piece of code was hiding my radio buttons.

```
button:focus,
button:active,
button:hover
{
   outline:0px !important;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Comment: need to see some code, perhaps there is a hover event set somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just added the code. There's no hover event set elsewhere. Actually if I force the state of the radio directly chrome developer tools. Radio buttons disappear when it's :hover, :active, :focus.   Only :visited state won't affect these radio buttons.

Comment: Most likely, this is set in your loaded `CSS`. Something similar to `.some-parent:hover input[type=radio] {display: none;}`. It's only an example. What you need to do in order to get a proper answer is create a [mcve] of your problem, using the SO snippet tool or any other online snippet tool available (jsfiddle, codepen, etc).

Comment: @Z.Vincent It does not happen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as5rt9ux/) in Chrome. Can you add all relevant CSS styles?

Comment: @zgood Thx bro! I solved this issue by removing the above CSS code.